# Modify files without losing customization after updates

Tags: customization

I would like to know what is the best way to modify a file in Wordpress, such as header.php or single.php so when you update the theme, the changes remain there. I am not sure if this can be done with a child theme or if a plugin is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make changes to the template files (e.g. header.php, single.php, etc) you should create a child theme.

[Here's the Codex link to help you create your Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Thanks @Natalia - I follow this other tutorial and it was easier: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial

Comment: Whatever you find easier! I always consult the Codex.
Glad I've helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

when you use a theme that will be updated, make a child theme

you just have to copy the header.php from the parent to the child and the child version will be used by WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that your modifications are preserved.

How to create a child theme -> [Wordpress Codex quick guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

If you want to create functionality that will be reused in your another projects, create plugins.

Thanks

Vee